# Showing that multivariable function with piecewise construction is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> Let $f(x_1,x_2)= x_2-x_1^2$, when $x_2 > x_1^2$ and $f(x_1,x_2)=0$, when $|x_2|\le x_1^2$, lastly $f(x_1,x_2)=x_2+x^2_1$ when $x_2 < -x_1^2.$ Show that $f$ is continuous.

I cannot see where the possible points of discontinuity would occur? When $x_2 > x_1^2$ the map $f$ is continuous as a polynomial and the same holds when $x_2<-x_1^2$. When $|x_2|\le x^2_1$ we have that $f$ is constant so also continuous. Any hints on where the possible discontinuities are?

Comment: If you change the definition to $f(x_1,x_2)=13$ when $|x_2|\le x_1^2$, is $f$ still continuous? Can you see where your argument breaks?

Comment: I was able to graph the function so I think I have a visual understanding why the argument breaks. To show continuity I am to consider limits at $0$?

Comment: You have to consider continuity at all points where the distinct domains meet, that is, at all points with $|x_2| = x_2^2$.

Comment: How does this fit to the epsilon delta formulation? Do I take $|f(x_1,x_2) - f(x_1', x_2')|$, where $(x_1',x_2')$ is such a point that $|x_1|=x_2^2$?

Comment: @MartinR You say that I have to consider the continuity at points with $|x_2|=x_1^2$, but aren't these points exactly the ones where $g \equiv 0$? Which is continuous.

Comment: Consider the example $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, defined as $f(x) = 1$ if $x > 0$ and $f(x) = 0$ if $x \le 0$. Is $f$ continuous at $x=0$?

Comment: It is not since there isn't a neighborhood $U$ of $0$ in the domain that would contain the preimage of some neighborhood $V$ of $0$ in the codomain. The main issue I have is that I don't know where to start with this condition $|x_2| = x_1^2$.